# Have a 32-64bit problem with OpenCV and Qt

Tags: qt, opencv, mingw-w64, mingw32

I have used OpenCV 3.2.0 since a long time ago. 
Recently, I need to implement face detection with landmark detection so I decided to build the OpenCV again with extra OpenCV modules.
However, it seems that OpenCV 3.2.0 is not compatible with the latest extra OpenCV modules so I have to build it with the latest OpenCV (which is 4.0.0)

The problem is, I'm in a Catch 22 situation.

**1. If I use mingw 32bit 5.1.0 to build OpenCV (which is a compiler bundled with Qt), I have a following error**

> CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a: member
>   CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a(vs_version.rc.obj) in archive is
>   not an object

**2. If I use mingw 64bit 8.1.0 to build OpenCV, it works fine. However there are two situations that give me an error.**

2.1. If I use mingw 32bit 5.1.0 to build a Qt Project with those OpenCV libs, it gives a following error.

> D:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_core400.dll:-1: error: file not
>   recognized: File format not recognized

I suspect that this has something to do with 32-64bit problem. The compiler may expect 32bit libs, but the libs are 64bit format because the compiler used to build OpenCV was 64bit mingw.

```
file format pei-i386
file format pei-x86-64
```

The first one is the file format of the OpenCV 3.2.0 libs which I used in the past and worked fine with Qt.
The second one is the file format of the OpenCV 4.0.0 libs newly built.

2.2 If I use mingw 64bit 8.1.0 to build a Qt Project with those OpenCV libs, it gives a following error.

> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status

I suspect that this occurred because basically Qt is for 32-bit, not 64-bit.

What I want to do is that building OpenCV 4.0.0 so that somehow the file format of those OpenCV libs is pei-i386, not pei-x86-64.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 5 exit status` is not a diagnostic. It is
GCC saying "Your linkage failed :( Bye.". The linker's diagnostics precede
this farewell in the buildlog, and they are what you need to post to get
help with the linkage failure. Just post the complete buildlog, verbatim.

Comment: also you know you can download the [opencv_contrib for version 3.2.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases)? better to use the latest version, though

Comment: Your assumption regarding the Qt libs is correct. I would recommend you to build Qt yourself with the mingw 64 8.1.0

Comment: @Mike Kinghan It was the only error message. Is there a way for me to get the verbose buildlog in that case?

Comment: @James Probably, but I don't know what your build-system is or how you are running it.