# Is it possible to simulate Signal & slot in IPC?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ipc

I found that Qt and OpenCV 4.0.0 are not compatible because the former one is for 32bit, and the latter one is for 64bit. (Building 64bit Qt was quite puzzling to me) So, I decided to use IPC to implement my application. However, I have no experience of using it, but just knowing it theoretically.

This is what I want to implement : There are two processes. The first one reads a frame from webcam (It is combined with Qt), sends it to the second one as a form of cv::Mat. And the second one does landmark detection, draws a circle in the Mat and resends it to the first one.

What I'm curious about is that how the second process knows that the frame(Mat) has been sent. 
If I implement it like following, it seems quite inefficient.

```
while(nothing in shared memory);
do_something()
```

The second process should sleep while there is no frame(Mat) to be processed, and be woke up by the first process when there's one.
How can I implement such thing?

Comment: To involve IPC, because one of the libraries hasn't been build for the right architecture is a questionable decision. If you don't know the way to the next bakery shop just ask somebody. Calling the police is the 2nd best option although they probably could solve your issue as well. (But you probably have to pay a lot for this.) ;-)

Comment: _"because the former one is for 32bit"_ [Huh?](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263199/have-a-32-64bit-problem-with-opencv-and-qt Qt which I'm using now is not compatible with 64bit MinGW. However, I have to use 64bit MinGW to be compatible with OpenCV 4.0.0. So I need to rebuild Qt as 64bit but it happens to be too complex for me.

Comment: @James Implementing a solution using IPC would be way more complex believe me.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'll try it again then as much as possible.

Comment: compile Qt in 64 bit yourself

Comment: there is a signal and slot feature in C++11std library  afaik.

Comment: have you even tried compiling Qt for mingw64? How about just following this guide: https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit

Comment: Also, there are pre-made Qt packages for msys you could use: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-qt5/PKGBUILD